# Simplifying conditions with Optional.ofNullable()

Tags: java, performance, oop, nullpointerexception, java-stream

I'm wondering if there is an exit in the use of `Optional.ofNullable()`

```
for(String name: names){
  if(name != null)
     person = "Mr./Mrs."+name;
  else
      continue;
  greeting(person);
}
```

My code is like above. I want to check the argument before calling the function. I have similar codes in my class and to reduce complexity I want to use `Optional.Nullable()`.

Is there a way to apply `Optional.Nullable()` in here? Or is there another way to help me to reduce complexity of multiple if checks to check null variables? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

> My code is like above. I want to check the argument before calling the
> function. I have similar codes in my class and to reduce complexity I
> want to use Optional.Nullable().

You have several options depending on your given context:

**Approach 1: Rearrange the conditionals**

```
  for(String name: names){
        if(name != null) {
            person = "Mr./Mrs." + name;
            greeting(person);
            ... 
        }
    }
```

or :

```
    for(String name: names){
        if(name == null)
            continue;
        person = "Mr./Mrs." + name;
        greeting(person);
        ...
    }
```

**Approach 2: Using Optional**

```
for(String name: names){     
   Optional.ofNullable(name)
           .map("Mr/Mrs"::concat)
           .ifPresent(YourClass::greeting); 
}
```

the `YourClass` is just a place holder for the class where the method `greeting` was defined.

**Approach 3: Using Streams**

Assuming that names is a `Collection`, then you are actually better off using Java Streams, namely:

```
names.stream()
     .filter(Objects::nonNull)
     .forEach(name -> greeting("Mr./Mrs."+name));
```

If names is an array of `String`s then you can do:

```
Arrays.stream(names)
      .filter(Objects::nonNull)
      .forEach(name -> greeting("Mr./Mrs."+name));
```

Comment: What if I want to check it for a single variable? Is there a way to check a variable is null or not and if so, then make sure it doesn't enter this block?

Comment: @Vincent Depends on the context really, you can do Optional.ofNullable(name).map(n -> ).map(p -> greeting()) (like suggested in the comments) or simply if(name != null){ person = "Mr./Mrs."+name; greeting(person);}

Answer (score 2):

You can involve `Optional`:

```
for (String name : names) {
  Optional.ofNullable(name).map(n -> "Mr/Mrs" + name).map(p -> greeting(p));
}
```

or `Stream`s:

```
names.stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .map(n -> "Mr./Mrs." + name)
    .forEach(p -> greeting(p));
```

But there's really no advantage to doing either. It's certainly not more performant to do so.

Comment: `.map(p -> greeting(p))` requires `greeting` to return a value. Why not use `.ifPresent(p -> greeting(p))`… And `.map(n -> "Mr./Mrs." + name)` uses a different names (`n` and `name`). When you use `.map("Mr./Mrs."::concat)` instead, you don’t need to deal with names at all. But generally, `if(name != null) greeting("Mr./Mrs." + name);` still is simpler than both approaches.